# Does anyone know the DB layer for CouchDB in YCSB?

Tags: couchdb, benchmarking, ycsb

I want to use YCSB to check CouchDB.But I found there is no DB layer for CouchDB.Anyone have a DB layer for CouchDB in YCSB?

Comment: Very interesting. I *think* there is no CouchDB layer but I will leave this question to be answered by others who know better than me. (Or for a future answer once it becomes available.)

Answer (score 1):

Yes I have written it for kundera-couchdb benchmarking, you can find it here.
https://github.com/impetus-opensource/Kundera/blob/trunk/test/benchmark/ycsb/src/main/java/com/impetus/kundera/ycsb/benchmark/CouchDBNativeClient.java

Please let me konw of you face any problem.